# What kind of regular expression matching is implemented in Pharo?

Tags: regex, implementation, string-matching, smalltalk, pharo

I came across this question in computer science stack exchange, [Theory behind regex implementations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135340/theory-behind-regex-implementations), pointing to this paper, [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast
(but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html), discussing the fact there is two big families of regular expression(-like) implementations, and their relative merits. One is implemented, for example, by Awk, Tcl, GNU grep, and GNU awk. The other, for example, by Perl, Python, Ruby, Java. So I ask, what implementation does Pharo use?

Comment: Does http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/Regex.pdf or https://github.com/astares/Pharo-Regex-Tools help?

Comment: Ok, I have also found https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/UpdatedPharoByExample/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/Regex/Regex.html and http://www.squeaksource.com/@fTghDTXLgENXRnYp/wBL3-zle. So, it is some specific "minified" regex flavor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but in what camp does this "minified" regex flavor fall, among the two mentioned in the question?

Comment: You can easily check what the falvor is by trying out a couple of specific constructs. If `\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|,` matches all commas but those inside parentheses, then it is PCRE. If `^[^]+$` matches a whole string with all line breaks, it is ECMAScript, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to look at this.

Out of the box, one can do

[image]

The help will give you more details:

[image: Pharo Regex Help]

That being said, if you want to parse complex stuff, you can look into PetitParser, SmaCC and other things of that kind which will also implement objects that can match against other things, like strings and more.

And FuzzyMatcher may also be of interest:

[image: FuzzyMatcher]